# BartyCrouch - Base language detection

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, interface-builder

I have a Xcode ObjC project, with following language-related properties in project.pbxproj

```
developmentRegion = English;
knownRegions = ( en, Base, sk, cs, );
```

Also the Info.plist has `<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>` set to `<string>en</string>`.
All the designer files (storyboard, views etc.) are designed in English.

Whenever I run `bartycrouch interfaces -p "."` in the project root folder, I get all the *.strings files updated, however all the strings from the designer files are written into files in the cs.lproj folder (where the Czech language is supposed to be) instead of the en.proj folder.

Is there something wrong with my project? Or is there a way (parameter?) to specify my base language for bartycrouch?

I opened an issue on project GitHub (https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch/issues/91) but no reaction for two weeks, so I hope that I'll find more active users here.

Comment: I was able to get solution in the original GitHub issue https://github.com/Flinesoft/BartyCrouch/issues/91#issuecomment-388358442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered this question on the related GitHub issue, but let me explain it here, too for purposes of completeness:

### Problem explanation

Here's an extract of the changes happening in `cs.lproj` when BartyCrouch runs in your project:
[image]

Let's also have a look at the same entry in the language `sk.lproj`:
[image]

At first sight one might think, why is BartyCrouch replacing the correct Czech translation with the English one? And why isn't it doing so in the Slovak language?

Here's what's happening: If you take a look at the comment, you'll notice that it's the same for both languages. As a matter of fact, when creating the Strings files the first time in Xcode, Xcode will automatically take the values from the XIB or Storyboard and put them into the comments. It will also never change the comment value, even if you make changes in the XIB or Storyboard file, leaving you to have three different values for every entry: The actual value, the comment value and the XIB/Storyboard value. At the beginning the latter two are the same, but since Xcode doesn't update them, they tend to be different over time.

Since we can see that in the comment the value is of Czech language, I can assume that at the time where you first let Xcode generate the Strings files, your XIB or Storyboard had values in Czech language. It seems you later have changed this and made every value within the XIB or Storyboard be of English language. BartyCrouch has a feature built-in that will automatically update the comment value for you. So that's why we are seeing a change in the comment line for both example languages above. An additional feature of BartyCrouch is to – in case the comment value matches the real value exactly – to also update the real value. Since the actual value of the Czech translation is the same as the comment value, this is what happened here and what made BartyCrouch also update the value and replace it with the new English value which it found in the XIB or Storyboard file.

### Solution

Now that we know what the problem is, let's examine what can be done to solve this problem and/or to prevent it in the future:

1. To prevent this issue from happening again is to use English (or whatever language) in the XIB or Storyboard file from the beginning and never changing the language.
2. When the language is changed though, one manual way to fix it is to update the comment values to the new language manually. For example:

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Proveďte synchronizaci."; ObjectID = "RvR-Nz-aYE"; */
```

would need to be manually changed to

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Sync to get data."; ObjectID = "RvR-Nz-aYE"; */
```

3. Alternatively, you can also let BartyCrouch do its work and revert the wrong changes manually once (keeping the comment changes though!). From then on (as long as you don't change the language again) the issue shouldn't happen again. This is the way I recommend you to fix this issue – with the help of a Git GUI tool (like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com)) this shouldn't take very long.

I hope I could help.